# mongodb a query to remove out of date information

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Basically I have a query of

> return Images.find({'tags': tag}, {'sort': {'created_time': -1},
>   'limit': 6})

What it does is get the latest 6 documents that have a tag in tags. Now we know that any other tag that get matched after that is not needed. Is there a way to remove other Images that matches tag after the 6 one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are basically asking how you can delete more than 6?

You can remove the limit. This way you will get a full cursor back from there you can continue past the 6th element and continue removing as you wish.

Comment: What I meant was I only want to keep the first 6(where my original query is) and delete all the others where it should have been found if the {limit: 6} was not there. Sorry for my bad English. I hope this clear it up.

Comment: @JonathanShepherd You can use `{skip:6}` this way the first document you pick will be the 7th in the result set

Comment: and do I have to iterate over the result? This sounds very very inefficient.

Comment: @JonathanShepherd Indeed though your current code looks like that's what you need to do however if you are just looking to delete them without any further operations then in this case I would extract those 6, save them to an array, run the query to remove all rows without skip or limit then resaved those 6 bacvk to db